# DASH: Long-Running callback that streams tokens into a Markdown component

Tags: plotly-dash, chatgpt-api

I am using DASH to build an all-Python client for a chat application that is backed by some ChatGPT/OpenAI model (and additional processing). Calculating the response for the user can easily take 60 seconds and longer, but the protocol allows to stream tokens (i.e. words) incrementally, so the user can already read early parts of the reply while the later parts are still being calculated.

I was wondering how to best do this with DASH...

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

After some tinkering I ended up using a callback with `background=True` and `progress=Output(....)`, which appears to be designed to update progress bars, but seems to work quite well for my problem.

Below is an isolated example of what I am using (simulating the streamed response with a delayed generator).

I feel like I am abusing a feature so there might be better ways to achieve token streaming in a DASH app or there might be looming issues with this approach -- please let me know if you have a comment either way.

```py
import time
import dash
from dash import html, dcc
from dash.long_callback import DiskcacheLongCallbackManager
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

## Diskcache
import diskcache
cache = diskcache.Cache("./cache")
long_callback_manager = DiskcacheLongCallbackManager(cache)

app = dash.Dash(__name__, long_callback_manager=long_callback_manager)
app.layout = html.Div([
        dbc.Button("Start", id="start_button"),
        dcc.Markdown(id="progress_output"),
    ]
)

@app.callback(
    output=Output("progress_output", "children"),
    inputs=[Input("start_button", "n_clicks")],
    progress=Output("progress_output", "children"),
    progress_default="",
    background=True,
    interval=100,
)
def read_message(set_progress, n_clicks):
    if n_clicks is None:
        raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate

    state = ""

    for chunk in read_chunk():
        # append the chunk
        state += chunk
        # Update the progress component
        set_progress(state)
        
    # Return the final result
    return state


def read_chunk():
    reply = """
    An h1 header
    ============

    Paragraphs are separated by a blank line.

    2nd paragraph. *Italic*, **bold**, and `monospace`. Itemized lists
    look like:

    * this one
    * that one
    * the other one

    Note that --- not considering the asterisk --- the actual text
    content starts at 4-columns in.

    > Block quotes are
    > written like so.
    >
    > They can span multiple paragraphs,
    > if you like.

    Use 3 dashes for an em-dash. Use 2 dashes for ranges (ex., "it's all
    in chapters 12--14"). Three dots ... will be converted to an ellipsis.
    Unicode is supported. ☺
    """
    chunks = [word + " " for word in reply.split(" ")]
    for chunk in chunks:
        # Simulate some work
        time.sleep(0.02)
        yield chunk

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

The result looks like this:
[image]